# How to reset a private blockchain?

Tags: private-blockchain, parity

If I am testing a private blockchain and I want to reset it, and delete all contracts, etc., what needs to be deleted?

Is it enough to delete the .parity folder on every node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

Delete this file:

.parity/keys//address_book.json

Answer (score 3):

With

```
parity --chain dev db kill
```

If you have your own config.json, it works the same:

```
parity --chain config.json db kill
```

Note, you have to do it on all nodes running that chain/config.

Comment: I did this.  I also deleted the chains, signer, dapps, and cache directories under .parity/.  I did this on all nodes.  But the old contracts still show up as options to "Transfer" ETH to.

Comment: Ah, you have to clear your browser cache (local storage).

Comment: I did that and anyway, I don't allow any local storage to my browser.  I just checked now and there are no applications that are permitted to use local storage on my browser.  But I hit "clear now" anyway and the old contracts are still visible.

Comment: Then I have no idea what you are talking about. Maybe hit me up on Gitter and share some screenshots.